# Counting occurrences of a word in a file, counting the number of occurrences of any repeated word. Perl

Tags: regex, perl, count, hashmap, tr

I use a regex to read a file line by line, then split this into scalar variables as below, regex works fine.

```
while (<GTFFILE>) {

        if ($_ =~ /(^\d)\s+\w+\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+\.\s+\W\s+\.\s+(\w+\_\w+\s+\"\w+\"\;)/){

    my $gene = $1;
    my $type = $2;
    my $start = $3;
    my $end = $4;
    my $geneId = $5;
```

Attempting to produce a hash from values taken from regex.

```
    $featurestart{$start} = $start;
    $featureend{$end} = $end;
```

I need to find the length of the exons, using the hash I produced from the regex. This is done per line, but I am receiving error: Missing $ on loop variable. Any ideas?

```
            for each ($_) { 
            $exonlength = ($featureend{$_} - $featurestart{$_});
            printf ("Exon lengths: = %1.1f\n", $exonlength);
            }
```

Here I am clueless, I want to find the occurrences of a each word in the $geneId. HOw would I go about matching unknown words, and counting the distinct occurrences of each unknown word? I am guessing some sort of function to cluster together, perhaps in a hash/array the repeats of a word together then count each cluster somehow?

```
                    $geneCount{$geneId} = $type; 
                foreach $geneId { 

                }
        }   
    }
}
```

Each line of a GTF file is: 
1   unknown exon    3204563 3207049 .   -   .   gene_id "Xkr4"; gene_name "Xkr4"; p_id "P15240"; transcript_id "NM_001011874.1"; tss_id "TSS13146";
This is what the regex is reading. The exon varies between lines, it can be exon, or cds etc, only one or the other per line, so counting the occurrences of the word exon, counts the number of exons on the file. The two numbers seperated by a space after 'exon' are coordinates, the exon length is to be calculated by subtracting the second number from the first. The phrases seperated by ';' are grouped as geneId. For these I want to count the occurrences of this section throughout the whole file, similarly to exon, this changes, however it is unknown what the string might be, so the idea is to find how many different strings in this variable occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there are several issues. First allow me to put the obligatory link to https://metacpan.org/pod/Bio::Perl that i always itch to make when anyone mentions genes and parses files.

When you get to

```
if ($_ =~ /exon/)
```

`$_` is still the whole line. So you check whether the current line has the string "exon" in it. So i assume you want to count occurrences of that string? Sadly `tr///` will not do that for you. Instead it will replace every "e", "x", "o" or "n" with itself and count how often that has happened. So you count the characters, not the words "exon". If you insist on this clunky way of counting `s/exon/exon/g` instead of the `tr///` stuff should work.

edit:
Okay, sorry i had to interrupt writing.

For your error: What are you trying to loop over? If you mean

```
foreach ($_) {
```

then that does not make a lot of sense as `$_` is only one element. And what is the length of an exon? I have no idea what an exon is at all.
But i assume you meant to fill your hashes in some other way. As is, they have the same keys as values, so it does not really make a lot of sense to have them in the first place.

If you want help with anything after the counting, you certainly will have to give more information what your input looks like and what you are trying to do.

edit 2 After the question has been edited:

Okay, if that is what you want to do, you can do something like the following:

```
my $numberOfExon = 0;   # We will increase this whenever we meet an exon.
my @exonLength;         # This array will store all the exon lengths          
my %geneCount;          # This hash will store the counts per geneId

while (<GTFFILE>) {

    if ($_ =~ /(^\d)\s+\w+\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+\.\s+\W\s+\.\s+(\w+\_\w+\s+\"\w+\"\;)/){

        my $gene = $1;
        my $type = $2;
        my $start = $3;
        my $end = $4;
        my $geneId = $5;

        if ($_ =~ /exon/){

            $numberOfExon++;              # just count the lines that have exon in them
            my $length = $end - $start;   # just calculate the length

            push @exonLength, $length;    # Do with the length whatever you want

            $geneCount{$geneId}++;        # Increase the number of times this Id was seen
                                          # If this was the first time, a new field is created
        }
    }
}

print "Number of Exon: $numberOfExon \n";
print "Count of Ids:\n";
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\%geneCount);
```

This counts only the Ids of exons, not of other whatevers. If you want the others, just put `geneCount{geneId}++` after the first `}` (the if exon part).

Comment: Thank you for responding, I have edited my question to make it clearer for you. Should show now what the input file looks like. Would an array rather than a hash be more useful do you think?

Comment: Thanks again, would you be able to tell me how I would go about printing the count of exons, and the count of different geneIds? I have attempted your solution, but it is still printing a very larger number of numbers, rather than a single count value for each.

Comment: Count of Ids:
$VAR1 = {};
Sorry, I pressed enter too soon, I meant to say this is what it prints for the geneId count?

Comment: Sorry, I realise I just put the print statement in the wrong place, but now it is printing just one of the instances out: Count of Ids:
$VAR1 = {
          '"Xkr4";' => 1
        };
?

Comment: And you are sure, you put it into the right spot now? After the while loop? And there really are more than one lines with "exon" in them in the file?

Comment: Yes, the exons are not a problem anymore (thanks), there are 68001 of them, which is correct. It is the count of each different instance of the geneId that does not seem to be printing nicely? I have tried in every curly brace to ensure that is not the issue?

Comment: I asked because as is, it will only count the instances of geneId in those lines that contain "exon". Could you link one of those files? I do not really see why it should only count a single geneId.

Comment: https://usegalaxy.org/library_common/ldda_info?library_id=4ab3a886a95d362e&show_deleted=False&cntrller=library&folder_id=57764628a4cf79d3&use_panels=False&id=05ccf9e20303b392 This is a link to an example .gtf file, which is the file type I need to read. I cannot find an example exactly like mine, but my regex works with my file (it is slightly different in terms of data types to this example, as in first $1 is a digit etc)

Comment: 1 unknown exon 3204563 3207049 . - . gene_id "Xkr4"; gene_name "Xkr4"; p_id "P15240"; transcript_id "NM_001011874.1"; tss_id "TSS13146";
1 unknown stop_codon 3206103 3206105 . - . gene_id "Xkr4"; gene_name "Xkr4"; p_id "P15240"; transcript_id "NM_001011874.1"; tss_id "TSS13146";
1 unknown CDS 3206106 3207049 . - 2 gene_id "Xkr4"; gene_name "Xkr4"; p_id "P15240"; transcript_id "NM_001011874.1"; tss_id "TSS13146";
1 unknown CDS 3411783 3411982 . - 1 gene_id "Xkr4"; gene_name "Xkr4"; p_id "P15240"; transcript_id "NM_001011874.1"; tss_id "TSS13146";

For a tester all I can do is try on small sec-

Comment: -tion, the file is too large, and only downloadable, the links are on databases that cannot be linked for the proper format. If you can see how the line is split, each line starting with 1 unknown...
However, these change further through the file, as does gene id.

Comment: In those example lines you provided, your main regex only takes two as valid. Maybe that is a problem? You expect to see `. - .` but the lines have `. - 2` or another number. If i correct that in the sample, the script i posted correctly states the ids for me. All in all, your way of parsing the line is probably not optimal. `my @fields = split ' '` to split the line on spaces and then finding your desired information in the array like `$geneId = $fields[9]` for example.

Comment: Unfortunately the use of regex in this particular program is mandatory. I had thought that the use of '.' in the regex was for any character? And so that would cover whether it was a digit or '.' or '-'? Or should I use \W for that?

Comment: The use of `.` would mean any character indeed. But you escape the dot by writing `\.` and that means a literal dot. For characters with a special meaning, `\\` removes that special meaning.

Comment: Thank you for your consistent help @DeVadder